# Are these $ L^2 $ norms equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Could anyone help me to prove that these two norms are equivalent?
The norms are
$$\Vert \nabla^{2} f\Vert_{L^{2}} $$ and $$ \Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^{2}}.$$
Maybe it is possible to prove using the Fourier Transform?

Comment: Doesn't $\Delta$ by definition mean $\nabla^2$, so that there is nothing to prove...?

Comment: This is not well defined. Inner or outer tensor product with $\nabla$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\nabla^2$ is just another notation for div grad, then the two are equivalent because $\Delta f=\pm\nabla^2 f$, sign convention due to author's choice.

On the other hand, if $\nabla^2$ means the Hessian, then taking Fourier transform,
$$
\lVert \partial_{ij}f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2=\lVert \omega_i\omega_j(\mathcal{F}f)(\omega)\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\lVert\nabla^2 f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
&=
\sum_{i,j}\lVert (\omega_i\omega_j)(\mathcal{F}f)(\omega)\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2\\
&\leq\sum_{i,j}\frac12\lVert(\omega_i^2+\omega_j^2)(\mathcal{F}f)(\omega)\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2\\
&=n\sum_i\lVert\omega_i^2(\mathcal{F}f)(\omega)\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2\\
&=n\lVert\Delta f\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2
\end{align*}
and the other bound is clear.

Comment: It's exactly what i was lookin for. Could you explain  what the $ \omega_i \omega_j$ are? And what about the first inequality?

Comment: $\omega_i$ is the $i$-th component of $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  The other bound is just the pointwise bound $\sum_{i,j}(\partial_{ij}f)^2\geq\sum_i(\partial_{ii}f)^2\geq\frac1n(\sum_i \partial_{ii}f)^2$ where the first is ignoring some terms, the second is Cauchy-Schwarz, integrated over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a notational difference, with the definition being 
$$ \nabla^2 f = \Delta f = \sum_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f $$

Therefore the norms are the same.

I will say that the $\nabla^2 $ notation seems to appear much more in physics heavy areas of mathematics, while the $\Delta f$ notation is much more common in analysis and other less physical areas of mathematics. But that's not a hard-and-fast rule, just a slight cultural observation. The former notation comes from a combination of the gradient and the divergence notation you see pop up in vector calculus.